# Вызвать BSOD в 64-битном приложении

Tags: delphi, ассемблер

```
unit BSOD;

interface

uses
  WinAPI.Windows;

procedure Crash;

function RtlSetProcessIsCritical(unu: Cardinal; proc: Pointer; doi: Cardinal): Integer; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll';
function RtlAdjustPrivilege(Privilege: Cardinal; Enable: Boolean; CurrentThread: Boolean; out OldPrivilege: Boolean): Cardinal; stdcall; external 'ntdll';

implementation

procedure Crash;
asm
  lea eax, dword[esp+12]
  //invoke RtlAdjustPrivilege, 20, 1, 0, eax
  push eax
  push 0
  push 1
  push 20
  call RtlAdjustPrivilege
  //invoke RtlSetProcessIsCritical, 1, 0, 0
  push 0
  push 0
  push 1
  call RtlSetProcessIsCritical
  call ExitProcess
end;

end.
```

В 32-битном приложении, если вызвать **Crash**, то винда крашится.

Как заставить этот код работать в 64-битном приложении?

Comment: А если вызвать функции явно, то также крешится? я даже не понимаю, зачем здесь применять ассемблер.

Comment: Этот код просто делает процесс критическим, такой процесс нельзя закрывать иначе будет BSOD. (весь смысл кода)
Если без ассемблера вызывать в x64 все ровно не работает.
С ассемблером быстрее (наверное), да и выглядит проще.

Comment: в Вашем случае вряд ли будет быстрее. А если и выиграете, то полтакта, максимум. И выглядеть обычным делфовым кодом будет красивее. Попробуйте.

Comment: Для меня данный код красивей, да и просто хочется понять и разобраться в чем причина.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не знаете, как написать код на ассемблере, то пишите вначале код на Delphi, смотрите, какой код генерирует компилятор (ставите брекпоинт в функции и когда дойдёте до него, открывайте окно дизассемблера `Ctrl+Alt+D`), берёте его за основу и улучшаете.

Вот для такого Delphi кода:

```
procedure Crash;
var
  VOldPrivilege: Boolean;
begin
  RtlAdjustPrivilege(20, True, False, VOldPrivilege);
  RtlSetProcessIsCritical(1, nil, 0);
  ExitProcess(1);
end;
```

при компиляции в 64-битном режиме, генерируется вот такой ассемблерный код:

```
  push rbp
  sub rsp,$30
  mov rbp,rsp
  mov ecx,$00000014
  mov dl,$01
  xor r8,r8
  lea r9,[rbp+$2f]
  call RtlAdjustPrivilege
  mov ecx,$00000001
  xor edx,edx
  xor r8,r8
  call RtlSetProcessIsCritical
  mov ecx,$00000001
  call ExitProcess
  lea rsp,[rbp+$30]
  pop rbp
  ret
```

А вот такой код для 32-битного режима, можете сравнить со своим:

```
  push ebp
  mov ebp,esp
  push ecx
  lea eax,[ebp-$01]
  push eax
  push $00
  push $01
  push $14
  call RtlAdjustPrivilege
  push $00
  push $00
  push $01
  call RtlSetProcessIsCritical
  push $01
  call ExitProcess
  pop ecx
  pop ebp
  ret
```

Отличие кода для разных платформ в том, что для x32 используется соглашение вызовов `stdcall` (параметры передаются через стек), а в x64 - `fastcall` (первые 4 параметра передаются через регистры, остальные через стек).

> При разработке соглашений по вызовам (calling conventions) для
>   архитектуры x86-64 решили положить конец существованию различных
>   вариантов вызова функций. В Win32 существовал целый ряд соглашений о
>   вызове: stdcall, cdecl, fastcall, thiscall и так далее. В Win64 только
>   одно «родное» соглашение по вызовам. Модификаторы подобные __cdecl
>   компилятором игнорируются. Думаю, что все согласятся в благородстве
>   такого резкого сокращение числа соглашений.
>
> Соглашение по вызовам на платформе x86-64 похоже на соглашение
>   fastcall, существующее в x86. В x64-соглашении первые четыре
>   целочисленных аргумента (слева направо) передаются в 64-битных
>   регистрах, выбранных специально для этой цели:
>
> RCX: 1-й целочисленный аргумент
>
> RDX: 2-й целочисленный аргумент
>
> R8: 3-й целочисленный аргумент
>
> R9: 4-й целочисленный аргумент
>
> Остальные целочисленные аргументы передаются через стек. Указатель
>   «this» считается целочисленным аргументом, поэтому он всегда
>   помещается в регистр RCX. Если передаются значения с плавающей точкой,
>   то первые четыре из них передаются в регистрах XMM0-XMM3, а
>   последующие — через стек.

Цитата отсюда: https://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/94340/

Comment: Спасибо! работает!
Вот такой вот код получился [http://pasted.co/146a7ae5](http://pasted.co/146a7ae5)
Не знаю на сколько он универсален но в Windows 10 работает.
Кто может потестите на разных системах и отпишитесь плиз.

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный выше код - это код, главная задача которого [сделать BSOD](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/43405/protecting-your-process-with-rtlsetprocessiscriti). Если кратко - если процесс помечен как критический функцией RtlSetProcessIsCritical и он завершился (все равно как), то винда также делать себе харакири (например, через bsod). По хорошему нужно вызвать RtlSetProcessIsCritical но с тремя нулями, что бы снять с себя этот флажок.

**UPD**

Вышеуказанная функция хочет прав админа. Иначе сделать процесс "критическим" нельзя. И это правильно.

Если хочется именно бсода (я правда не понимаю, зачем оно нужно нормальному человеку), то можно написать свой драйвер, главной задачей которого будет вызвать его по желанию.

Но если хочется бсод, что бы напугать пользователя, прав админа не хватает - можно использовать скринсейвер от MS - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bluescreen.aspx

Comment: Так у меня цель и вызвать **BSOD** в **x64**, а не предотвратить его.

Comment: Зачем весь этот геморрой если код работает? его просто надо заставить в x64 работать и всё.

Comment: с правами админа запускали?

Comment: Этот код без них и не работает.  
У меня среда запущена с правами админа, запускаемое приложение из нее имеет теже права.

Comment: значит пофиксили эту "особенность". Функция все равно была неоффициальной, поэтому требовать от нее "задокументированного поведения" не стоит.

Comment: Тут дело в особенности вызовов в x86 и x64 приложении. И там и там разный код нужен, только вот какой?...

Comment: Вы пробовали сделать это обычным делфовским кодом?

Comment: Да, и кажется у меня это получилось, попозже код выложу.
Но мне всё таки интересно как это на ассемблере сделать, заинтриговало.

Comment: procedure Crash;
    var
      OldPrivilege: Boolean;
    begin
      RtlAdjustPrivilege(20, True, True, OldPrivilege);
      RtlSetProcessIsCritical(1, nil, 0);
      ExitProcess(0);
    end;

код работает почему-то если только приложение из среды запускать